# How do I change the stock firmware in Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo to higher than 4.4 KitKat without rooting?

Tags: samsung, stock-android, device-firmware, android-versions

My Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo has Android Kitkat. Is there a way to upgrade (without rooting the phone) to a newer version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, no. Samsung support ends at KitKat due to its age.

There does seem to be [official CyanogenMod 12.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3-neo/orig-development/kernel-n1kernel-t3208957) (Android 5.1.1) and even [unofficial ResurrectionRemix](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3-neo/development/rom-resurrectionremix-v5-7-3-t3444376) (Android 6.0.1) available, but you will need root and/or recovery to flash them, so I'll not go into details.